# Plot multiple probability distribution function lines on one plot in MatLab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I'm new to matlab and am trying to work with three dimensional data. It has latitude, longitude and time as the three dimensions, and I want to create a PDF for each of these matrices and then put all of them on the same plot rather than have three separate PDF plots. I don't know how to create reproducible data for matlab for this question so if there are more questions I can provide more guidance (also would be happy to hear guidance about how to create reproducible 3 dimensional data).

Essentially I need help creating a probability distribution function for three dimensional data, and then I want to plot multiple PDF lines on the same figure.

I've tried using the histogram function and normplot() but neither has worked.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You talk about PDF "lines", but also 3D data, are you expecting a surface? Or even some 4D "thing" because it's a PDF (output) as a function of 3 inputs? It's not really clear what data you are working with, how you intend to manipulate it, or what your expected output might look like.

Comment: what you need is to animate your data, right? 2D or 3D since you mention time, it seems you are asking how to build a movie with the data, correct?